# How to create binary tree in parse cloud code

Tags: recursion, parse-platform, tree, save, parse-cloud-code

I need to create a tournament bracket in parse cloud code, however I am unable to do this since you cannot create a pointer to an unsaved object.

How am I supposed to go about initializing a tree like object with this constraint? I can't save each bracket as I loop through since the save function is asynchronous.

**Save Bracket Function**

```
console.log('create bracket / end qualifier');
tournament.save('bracket', createBracket(tournament.get('players')),
{
    success: function(result)
    {
        console.log("saved!");
        callback(result);
    },
    error: function(result, error)
    {
        console.log("failed!");
        console.log(error.message);
        callback(result);
    }
});
```

**Create Bracket Function**

```
function createBracket(players)
{
    console.log("Creating bracket");
    var bracket = new Parse.Object("Match");
    bracket.set('matchId', 1);

    var extraLayerCount = getLayerCount(players);

    for (var i = 0; i < extraLayerCount; i++)
    {
        console.log("Adding layer " + i);
        addLayer(bracket);
    }

    return bracket;
}
```

**Add Layer Function**

```
function addLayer(match)
{
    leftChild = match.get('leftChild');
    rightChild = match.get('rightChild');

    console.log("Checking if match has children");
    if (leftChild != null && rightChild != null)
    {
        console.log("Has children, telling children to add layers");
        addLayer(leftChild);
        addLayer(rightChild);
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("Creating new children");
        var leftChild = new Parse.Object("Match");
        leftChild.set('matchId', match.get('matchId') * 2);
        match.set('leftChild', leftChild);

        var rightChild = new Parse.Object("Match");
        rightChild.set('matchId', match.get('matchId') * 2 + 1);
        match.set('rightChild', rightChild);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution to this was to create it from the bottom up, so instead of:

```
          1
    2           3
4       5   6       7
```

It was

```
          7
    5           6
1       2   3       4
```

So I create each match in the bottom layer, then when they finish saving, create parents for each pair, save those, and continue doing that until there is 1 left, which I return as the first match of the tree :)